# Drawing circles like Photoshop's ellipse tool

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, drawing, pixel

### The Problem

I'm looking to draw a filled circle *exactly* like Photoshop's ellipse tool (down to the pixel).

I'm not trying to implement any anti-aliasing, so my problem can be viewed as a circular binary mask generation problem. Achieving the same circle seemed fairly straightforward on the outset, however, I've now implemented over 5 different circle drawing algorithms with none quite managing to match Photoshop for circle generation.

---

### Attempted Solutions

I'm using Python for programming the algorithm, numpy for array manipulation, OpenCV for its circle drawing implementation/flood filling, and Scikit-Image for its image saving capabilities. I'm phrasing the problem as a function that draws a circle of a given radius and x,y location on a given image and returns a new image with the circle drawn on it.

I've programmed/used the following circle drawing implementations:

1. Naive Pythagorean Approach
2. OpenCV's Circle
3. Bresenham's Circle
4. The Arithmetic Circle
5. Andres' Circle

---

### Testing the Solutions

These algorithms were tested in two different scenarios: A small, 10px radius circle and a large, 257px radius circle. The small circles were used to compare more obvious visual differences, while the large circles were used to compute an error metric against a circle of the same radius generated in Photoshop.

Here are the results from these tests:

#### Small Circles Test

The six algorithms above were instructed to draw a 10px radius circle at the centre of a 40x40px image. I've combined all the results for ease of comparison.

[image: Results]

- The blue circles are true, graphed circles scaled to fit the 20px diameter.

#### Large Circles Test

The six algorithms above were instructed to draw a 257px radius circle at the centre of a 2370x1770px image. Each of the algorithm generated circles was subtracted from a 257px radius circle drawn in Photoshop to get the difference.

For reference, the circle generated in Photoshop is here:

[image: here]

**Naive Pythagorean:**

- Pixels Different: **1082**
- Image of Difference Result:

[image: Results]

**OpenCV:**

- Pixels Different: **724**
- Image of Difference Result:

[image: Results]

**Bresenham:**

- Pixels Different: **251**
- Image of Difference Result:

[image: Results]

**Midpoint:**

- Pixels Different: **224**
- Image of Difference:

[image: Results]

**Arithmetic Circle:**

Optimization was performed on parameters in this implementation.

- Pixels Different (without optimization): **155**
- Pixels Different (with optimization): **107 (Best Result)**
- Image of Difference (with optimization):

[image: Results]

**Andres' Circle:**

- Pixels Difference: **155**
- Image of Difference:

[image: Results]

---

### Final Thoughts

At this stage, I've had the most success with using the Arithmetic circle algorithm, however, I'm still not 100% convinced that tweaking this algorithm will allow for emulation of Photoshop's ellipse drawing behaviour.

There are a couple edge cases when drawing circles in Photoshop that I've had no success in replicating whatsoever. Eg: A 2x2px circle is drawn as a 2x1 pixel rectangle.

Another odd behaviour is that circles at certain radius don't exhibit the octant symmetry utilized in most circle drawing behaviours. I would assume this is because the ellipse tool is for drawing ellipses which only exhibit quadrant symmetry. So even if a circle is being drawn that has octant symmetry, quadrants are still drawn, maybe?

As a final bit of food for thought, I drew overlapping circles in Photoshop of decreasing radius and alternating colour. Star-shaped geometry can be seen which is fairly similar to Bresenham circles drawn in a similar manner. This makes me wonder if Photoshop is using a modified Bresenham circle?

[image: colored]

Anyways, thanks for reading up to this point! It would be great to get some input on what I could do to make this more accurate.

Thank you!

---

### Code

The code for the above testing/implementations follows:

```py
import math

from skimage import io
import cv2
import numpy as np


def draw_octant_half_integer(circle_img, centre_x, centre_y, x, y):

    circle_img[centre_x + x, centre_y + y] = 255
    circle_img[centre_x + x, centre_y - y + 1] = 255
    circle_img[centre_x - x + 1, centre_y + y] = 255
    circle_img[centre_x - x + 1, centre_y - y + 1] = 255
    circle_img[centre_x + y, centre_y + x] = 255
    circle_img[centre_x + y, centre_y - x + 1] = 255
    circle_img[centre_x - y + 1, centre_y + x] = 255
    circle_img[centre_x - y + 1, centre_y - x + 1] = 255


def draw_octant(img, centre_x, centre_y, x, y):

    img[centre_x + x, centre_y + y] = 255
    img[centre_x - x, centre_y + y] = 255
    img[centre_x + x, centre_y - y] = 255
    img[centre_x - x, centre_y - y] = 255
    img[centre_x + y, centre_y + x] = 255
    img[centre_x - y, centre_y + x] = 255
    img[centre_x + y, centre_y - x] = 255
    img[centre_x - y, centre_y - x] = 255


def create_pythagorean_circle(img, centre_x, centre_y, radius):

    def point_on_circumference(x, y, centre_x, centre_y, radius):

        x -= centre_y
        y -= centre_x
        hypot = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)

        return hypot >= radius - 0.5 and hypot <= radius + 0.5

    circle_img = img.copy()
    height, width = circle_img.shape
    for y in range(0, height):
        for x in range(0, width):
            if point_on_circumference(x, y, centre_x, centre_y, radius):
                circle_img[x, y] = 255

    cv2.floodFill(circle_img, None, (int(centre_x), int(centre_y)), 255)

    return circle_img


def create_bresenham_circle(img, centre_y, centre_x, radius):

    height, width = img.shape
    circle_img = img.copy()
    x = 0
    y = radius
    d = 3 - 2 * radius

    draw_octant_half_integer(circle_img, centre_x, centre_y, x, y)
    while y >= x:
        x += 1
        if d > 0:
            y -= 1
            d = d + 4 * (x - y) - 10
        else:
            d = d + 4 * x + 6
        draw_octant_half_integer(circle_img, centre_x, centre_y, x, y)

    cv2.floodFill(circle_img, None, (int(centre_y), int(centre_x)), 255)
    return circle_img


def create_midpoint_circle(img, centre_y, centre_x, radius):

    x = radius
    y = 0
    circle_img = img.copy()
    p = 1 - radius

    circle_img[centre_x + x, centre_y + y] = 255
    if radius > 0:
        circle_img[centre_x + y, centre_y - x] = 255
        circle_img[centre_x - x + 1, centre_y + y] = 255
        circle_img[centre_x - y + 1, centre_y + x] = 255

    while x > y:
        y += 1
        if p < -1:
            p = p + 2 * y + 1
        else:
            x -= 1
            p = p + 2 * y - 2 * x + 1
        if x < y:
            break

        circle_img[centre_x + x, centre_y + y] = 255
        circle_img[centre_x - x + 1, centre_y + y] = 255
        circle_img[centre_x + x, centre_y - y + 1] = 255
        circle_img[centre_x - x + 1, centre_y - y + 1] = 255

        if x != y:
            circle_img[centre_x + y, centre_y + x] = 255
            circle_img[centre_x - y + 1, centre_y + x] = 255
            circle_img[centre_x + y, centre_y - x + 1] = 255
            circle_img[centre_x - y + 1, centre_y - x + 1] = 255

    cv2.floodFill(circle_img, None, (int(centre_y), int(centre_x)), 255)
    return circle_img


def create_arithmetic_circle(img, centre_x, centre_y, radius, up=0.5, down=0.5):

    def decision_parameter(x, y):
        hypot = x**2 + y**2
        return (radius - up)**2 <= hypot and hypot <= (radius + down)**2

    x = 1
    y = radius
    circle_img = img.copy()

    while y >= x:
        draw_octant_half_integer(circle_img, centre_x, centre_y, x, y)
        if decision_parameter(x, y - 1):
            y -= 1
        elif decision_parameter(x + 1, y):
            x += 1
        else:
            x += 1
            y -= 1

    circle_img = circle_img.astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.floodFill(circle_img, None, (int(centre_y), int(centre_x)), 255)
    return circle_img


def andres_circle(img, centre_x, centre_y, radius):

    x = 0
    y = int(radius)
    d = radius - 1
    circle_img = img.copy()

    while y >= x:
        draw_octant_half_integer(circle_img, centre_x, centre_y, x, y)
        if d <= 2 * (radius - y):
            d += 2 * y - 1
            y -= 1
        elif d > 2 * x:
            d -= 2 * x + 1
            x += 1
        else:
            d += 2 * (y - x - 1)
            x += 1
            y -= 1

    circle_img = circle_img.astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.floodFill(circle_img, None, (int(centre_y), int(centre_x)), 255)
    return circle_img


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Loading Constants

    photoshop_circle = cv2.imread("photoshop_circle.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    width = 2370
    height = 1770
    centre_x = width/2
    centre_y = height/2
    radius = 257
    img = np.zeros((height, width))
    img = img.astype(np.uint8)

    # Optimizing Arithmetic Circle

    # lowest_mse = np.inf
    # lowest_up = 0
    # lowest_down = 0
    # for up in np.linspace(0.76, 0.77, 100):
    #     for down in np.linspace(0.49, 0.50, 100):
    #         circle = create_arithmetic_circle(img, int(round(centre_y))-1, int(round(centre_x))-1, radius, up=up, down=down)
    #         diff = photoshop_circle - circle
    #         mse = np.sum(diff**2)
    #         print("MSE:", mse, "Up:", up, "Down:", down)

    #         if mse < lowest_mse:
    #             lowest_mse = mse
    #             lowest_up = up
    #             lowest_down = down

    # print("Optimal MSE:", lowest_mse, "Optimal Up:", lowest_up, "Lowest Down:", lowest_down)

    # Drawing/Computing Difference

    # circle = createPythagorasCircle(img, centre_x, centre_y, radius)
    # circle = cv2.circle(img.copy(), (int(centre_x), int(centre_y)), radius, 255, cv2.FILLED)
    # circle = create_bresenham_circle(img, int(round(centre_x))-1, int(round(centre_y))-1, radius)
    # circle = createMidpointCircle(img, int(round(centre_x))-1, int(round(centre_y))-1, radius)
    # Unoptimized
    # circle = create_arithmetic_circle(img, int(round(centre_y))-1, int(round(centre_x))-1, radius)
    # Optimized
    # circle = create_arithmetic_circle(img, int(round(centre_y))-1, int(round(centre_x))-1, radius, up=0.7638, down=0.4976)
    circle = andres_circle(img, int(round(centre_y))-1, int(round(centre_x))-1, radius)

    diff = photoshop_circle - circle
    diff[diff > 0] = 1
    error = np.sum(diff)
    print("Pixels Different:", error, "Radius:", radius)

    diff[diff < 0] = 255
    diff[diff > 0] = 255
    io.imsave("circle.png", diff, check_contrast=False)
```

Comment: It could be that Photoshop does not draw an actual circle, but uses a Bezier path to approximate a circle.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think you might be right. If I manually draw a circle with the curved pen tool in Photoshop, I can make a selection or fill the path such that it exactly replicates a drawn pixel circle. That still unfortunately leaves the logic up in the air as to how it's selecting these pixels.

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to create a perfect circle using Beziers, you can only do an approximation.  There are many ways to do the approximation, a search should lead you to a few of them.